# How to make a div expand

Tags: html, css

I have tried the clear, set special heights and all sorts so this is the problem.

My wrapper has a bg, however it won't scroll if the content expands. There are 2 cases right now, if height is set too 100% then the background stops at the pixel line where the bottom of the screen is and then no image after that, if it doesnt have height the bg stops just above half way on the page this is some of the css:

```
body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%
    padding: 0;
    background-color:#9B9D9E;
}

#container{
    width:1260px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper{
    background-image:url(../images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1260px;
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PqRhT/

Screen shot: http://tinypic.com/r/orjyw6/5

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your code does. Can you post an example on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Are you actually trying to make the div expand, or just position your background image correctly?

Comment: @SouthShoreAK I need to make the div expand as content is added meaning it brings the background down on the y-axis

Comment: Screen shot of the browser: the bg should repeat as it goes down http://tinypic.com/r/orjyw6/5

Comment: What are you gaining from `height:100%`? Just remove all of those and it should grow just fine...

Comment: @bhamlin When i do that i get this: JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dwxEG/ screenshot : http://tinypic.com/r/352jkzq/5

Comment: I see. I would recommend really trying to simplify your html, I think you're making it hard for yourself. There's no reason that `wrapper` should be `position:absolute`... there's really no reason that I can see in that screenshot for anything to be absolutely positioned. Put your background image on the body, build up your header on top of it, and let it just flow.

Comment: @bhamlin thanks for the reply, your right I have over complicated it. The thing is when i put it in the body the text and everything is still centered but the background isnt centered, new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dn4vA/

Comment: Whoops sorry i sorted it had to position the bg! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
#div:hover {hover is just one type of selector}
```

or

```
#div:hover #divOther {results in effecting another element}
```